# Handling user acting on UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

My goal is to open a specific screen when user clicks on a UILocalNotification from the iOS Notification Center.

Now if the app is being resumed from the background when user acts on the Notification, I notice didReceiveLocalNotification is called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Now I can get the userInfo dictionary from the UILocalNotification object and opens the proper screen.

Unfortunately, this same method is called also when my app publishes a UILocationNotification while the app is running in the foreground:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

How would I distinguish between the 2 cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It passes to you the `application` object that contains the state in its `.applicationState` property.

Consequently, you can make sure it is not active by testing...

```
if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive){
 // do your stuff
}
```

And that's it!